# Subversion svn admin?

Tags: svn

I am a beginner in Java and I need to setup subversion and I am following this guide
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html

The problem is that once I installed everything and then go to command line and typing svnadmin

I get the error:

'svnadmin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

So I am wondering where is the svnadmin executable file?

Comment: ensure the svn is your path?

Comment: Solved: it is not in the 1.6.5 version but in the 1.7

Comment: `svnadmin` is in both 1.6.5 and 1.7 (and many other earlier versions of SVN).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Subversion directory to your `PATH` statement. (I'm guessing you're using Windows because of the error message, especially the `batch file` portion.)

Right-click `Computer` in the `Start` menu, choose `Properties`, then `Advanced System Settings`. When the dialog opens for `System Settings`, click the `Environment Variables` button at the bottom. In the `User variables for <your user name>`, either edit the existing `PATH` if it exists or add one if it doesn't, and add the full location to your `SVN` folder. (I can't tell you what that folder location is, because I don't know what SVN you installed or where you installed it.)